# Send email using php and html forms

Tags: php, html, webforms, html-email

I have a form that I want to use to collect user information. I have a php that gets the information and stores in the variable. When user clicks submit button the form gest submitted and is successfully redirected to the thank you page. Bu for some reason I am not getting the email as expected. Can someone explain where I am doing things wrong.

Below are my HTML and PHP file. I will add javascript validation later. At this moment I just want to make the form submission working.

**PHP**

```
<?php

//This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo "ERROR. This page cannot be accessed directly";
}

//Variables from the form
$name               = $_POST['fullname'];
$ageGroup           = $_POST['ageGroup'];
$gender             = $_POST['gender'];
$visit              = $_POST['visit'];
$purposeOfVisit     = $_POST['purposeOfVisit'];
$otherReferrer      = $_POST['otherReferrer'];
$member             = $_POST['member'];
$socialMedia        = $_POST['socialMedia'];
$difficulties       = $_POST['difficulties'];
$easeOfUse          = $_POST['easeOfUse'];
$whatDifficulties   = $_POST['whatDifficulties'];
$specialCondition   = $_POST['specialCondition'];
$browser            = $_POST['browser'];
$preferredFormat    = $_POST['preferredFormat'];
$contentsForWebsite = $_POST['contentsForWebsite'];
$oldContents        = $_POST['oldContents'];
$expectations       = $_POST['expectations'];

$message = "Fullname:"; // will compose later

// Compose email
$email_from = "subash.adikari@gmail.com";
$email_subject = "Infinity User Questionnaire";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n".
"Here is the message:\n $message".

$to = "subash.adhikari@gmail.com";

$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: thankyou.html');


if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
    echo "Bad email value!";
    exit;
}

// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
          '(\r+)',
          '(\t+)',
          '(%0A+)',
          '(%0D+)',
          '(%08+)',
          '(%09+)'
          );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}
?>
```

you can download index.php [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3230707/web_form/index.php) if you want.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: is the site on a live website or on your localhost?

Comment: You don't prevent the code from loading after you determined there is nothing in `$_POST`. You only add a warning message. ALWAYS enable error_reporting.

Comment: Can you define `not as expected`?

Comment: @Starx I was expecting the email to be sent. But I am not getting any email while I submit the form.

Comment: Have you configured the `mail` function in your `php.ini` correctly? Refer to my answer for more information.

Comment: First make sure there is a mail server running on your host, or php.ini is pointing to one. Second, maybe you will want to take a look at PEAR's Mail class, which can handle SMTP relaying and other nice features: http://pear.php.net/package/Mail

Comment: Please note that on a Windows host, PHP's built-in mail() function will most likely fail, as I experienced for various reasons on WS hosts... Yet another bunch of MS bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my hosting service. I had to give them a call and they fixed it for me.

Comment: Please [mark this answer as the accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that the question does not show up as 'unanswered'.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is on your local machine, you need to first configure [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) in [`php.ini`](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php). For example, you might configure it to use your ISP's SMTP server:

```
[mail function]
SMTP = smtp.isp.net
smtp_port = 25
sendmail_from = me@isp.net
```

For more information, refer to the [PHP Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.smtp).

EDIT: I just tested your code on one of my servers, and the email sent as expected. This further leads me to believe there's something wrong with how you've configured the `mail()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest for you use PHPMailer from http://phpmailer.worxware.com/ to send mails. With PHPMailer you can track the errors, send mails in HTML and TEXT, change encoding and manage the word warpers.

Also, as someone said, your script doesn't prevent it from being executed directly and i think that headers must be finished with just new line character "\n" and not return carriage "\r".

Comment: While PHPMailer is good, it doesn't answer the original question. Besides, PHPMailer still uses `mail()`...